# Bootstrap 3 input group not displayed correctly

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am integrating bootstrap 3 into my own admin template and I have an issue with the display of an input group. I don't know which CSS rule breaks the display of input group. Here is the JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/Zw7BG/

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="form_weight" value="0" name="weight" class="form-control text-right">                          
    <span class="input-group-addon">Kg</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This question doesn't have much value here as BS 3 is still in early development. Changes between RC 1 and RC 2 were tremendous and many features are still being overhauled or finished. If this is a bug, you might want to create an issue on github instead.

Answer (score 1):

You just add a class pull-right in below code:

```
<input type="text" id="form_weight" value="0" name="weight" class="form-control text-right pull-right">                         
<span class="input-group-addon">Kg</span>
```

Pls check: http://jsfiddle.net/Zw7BG/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="display:inline-block;"` in the div tag with the input-group class.
This will override the display:table defined in the input-group class (which is the source of the bug/feature in BS 3.x).

```
<div class="input-group" style="display:inline-block;">
    <input type="text" id="form_weight" value="0" name="weight" class="form-control text-right">                          
    <span class="input-group-addon">Kg</span>
</div>
```